# background color for TextView

Tags: textview, android

When I make an attribute for changing the background color of a child `TextView`, it extends to the whole area rather than wrapping for the content even though the attribute value of `layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Please check if something is wrong and suggest the correct method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to give your first text view a property

```
android:layout_width="150dp";
```

also remove

```
android:padding="dp";
```

i thing it might solve your problem if it is not then place your code here i will check it.

Comment: i forgot to tell you remove padding att. from LinearLayout

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have made the value '150dp' for second 'TextView'. My doubt is why the 'wrap_content' is not working for the background color? Also, removed padding and checked still 'wrap_content' does not work well.

Comment: have you tried in android studio ? please check once in android studio